# In Mule how could I log the http response without changing the original output stream

Tags: java, mule

My Mule will do a HTTP call and response to my client, I want to log the HTTP call result, like status code and response body. At first I log the #[payload], but it's a stream, I know <object-to-string-transformer/> works, but I don't want to change the response, so I put the transformer into an enricher, but the result is still changed, why?

My code:

```
<http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://#[payload]" doc:name="Call Service in Pool"/>
<enricher source="#[payload]" target="#[flowVars['responseBody']]" doc:name="Message Enricher">
    <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
</enricher>
<logger level="INFO" doc:name="Log Response" message="response, http status: #[message.inboundProperties['http.status']], body: #[flowVars['responseBody']], org: #[payload]"/>
```

Log output:

```
org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: response, http status: 200, body: {"groupId":"group1", "formParam":"null"}, org: org.mule.transport.http.ReleasingInputStream@51dfd9b8
```

Client receives no body:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sat, 24 Aug 2013 10:55:49 +0800
Server: Mule EE Core Extensions/3.4.0
X-MULE_SESSION: 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
X-MULE_ENCODING: UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the standard behavior of streams: once you consumed it, it's consumed and, unless you reset it, it stays consumed with no more data available.

You can try using `mark()` before logging then `reset()` after (in MEL expression components) but there is no guarantee the actual stream implementation produced by Mule supports these methods.

Read the [InputStream JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/io/InputStream.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks David. But it seems the stream exists when I log it, it got lost when response to client

Comment: I never said the stream didn't exist, I'm saying you are consuming it if you log its content, ie you can't log its content and use it for the response unless the stream happens to support `mark()` and `reset()`, which remains to be tested.

Comment: OK, seems it's hard to do both log and response.

Answer (score 0):

Mule allows you to use Java in the MEL expressions. You could try something like this:

`#[String str = message.payloadAs(java.lang.String); java.io.InputStream ins = new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes()); message.payload = ins; return str;]"`